# MongoDB : Select top N records based on group by clause

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is my sample collection :-

```
{
"_id" : "fffdb22b-912d-4166-909b-7d0fe790ba2a", 
"companyVendorId" : "1001", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-01-02T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" : 100  
},
{
"_id" : "fff94874-27af-4a39-ae59-3a46b8c7f573", 
"companyVendorId" : "1002", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-01-25T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" : 200  
 },
{
"_id" : "fff94874-27af-4a39-ae59-3a46b8c7f573", 
"companyVendorId" : "1002", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-01-29T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" : 200  
 },

{
"_id" : "fff68faf-2f11-480f-83d2-bfcb45b12d5b", 
"companyVendorId" : "1004", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-01-12T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" : 500

 },

{
"_id" : "fff4dfaa-46cd-48e3-a871-1f086a2c5438", 
"companyVendorId" : "1005", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-02-13T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" :600

 },

 {
"_id" : "fff18ff2-015e-4ddc-81f2-a12ab3503d05", 
"companyVendorId" : "1006", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-02-08T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" : 700

},
{
"_id" : "ffeb16cd-ae1b-4c1e-aa93-d64347b5ff38", 
"companyVendorId" : "1007", 
"date" : ISODate("2019-02-18T05:30:00.000+05:30"),  
"amount" :800
}
```

**Requirement** :- I need top 2 vendors for each month (for current year) based on their amount, if more than one transactions are there for same "companyVendorId" in one month then we need to show sum of amount.

**Expected result** :-

```
{
"month":1
"companyVendorId" : "1004",     
"totalAmount" : 500 
 },
{
 "month":1
"companyVendorId" : "1002",     
"totalAmount" : 400

 },
{
"month":2
"companyVendorId" : "1007",         
"totalAmount" :800
 },

{
"month":2   
"companyVendorId" : "1006",     
"totalAmount" : 700

}
```

So far i am in between trying to make query, below query i am able to make :-

```
 db.getCollection('transaction').aggregate([
 {
"$project":
 {
 "amount": 1,
 "companyVendorId":1,

 "month": { "$month": "$date" }, "year": { "$year": "$date" }

 }
 },
 {
 "$match":
   {
    "year": 2020
   }

  }, {
 "$group": {
    "_id": {
    "month": "$month",
   "companyVendorId":"$companyVendorId"
    },
   "totalAmount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
     }
     }
    ])
```

This query giving me result based on my requirement but not able to select top 2 vendors.

Comment: Please include your expected output that matches your input as well

Comment: What would happen if sum of the same companyVendorId is greater than top `companyVendorId` ? Example: `companyVendorId" : "1002", "totalAmount" : 501`

Comment: @Valijon  So in this case  companyVendorId" : "1002"  record would come first .

Comment: @thammada  I am not sure what you are asking , expected output i have already added in my question and its matching with input as well,  In expected output  "month" field is showing that this record is for which month  and "companyVendorId" is already in my collection and "totalAmount" field specifying the total of "amount"  field.

SO  as per me my question is correct.

Comment: @HarishBagora Sorry, I missed that part. I might have scrolled past it somehow. and thought it was the input.

Answer (score 1):

One option to do it is:

1. Match last year documents and add the month
2. `$group` by month and vendor to get the vendor's amount per month
3. `$sort` to get them in order
4. `$group` again but by month, to get the vendors sorted per each month
5. keep only top 2 using `$slice`
6. format the results

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2019-12-31T23:59:59Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {$addFields: {month: {$month: "$date"}}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {vendor: "$companyVendorId", month: "$month"},
      amount: {$sum: "$amount"}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {amount: -1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.month",
      top: {
        $push: {
          companyVendorId: "$_id.vendor",
          amount: "$amount",
          month: "$_id.month"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {top: {$slice: ["$top", 2]}}},
  {$unwind: "$top"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$top"}},
  {$sort: {month: 1, amount: -1}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-HTGSen2fqy)

Answer (score 0):

A bit `complicated`. Stages 7 and 8 are the most complicated part, since you need to sum vendors with the same ID. If top `2...n` vendors are the same, we need to sum them all and count it as vendor `Nº1`. Same process for the vendor `Nº2`.

### Explanation

1. Stage 1. If you want to apply MongoDB indexes, we can filter records by `date` field. If no indexes, you can replace your 2 stages with mine.
2. Stage 2. We group by `month` and create two arrays with `companyVendorId` and `amount` values.
3. Stages 3-4. We flatten `data2` array to calculate `$max` / `$min` amounts per `companyVendorId`. This would help us to sum top vendors with the same `companyVendorId`.
4. Stages 5-6. Now we order vendors with the highest `amount` and define list of unique vendors with `$max` / `$min` amounts.
5. Stage 7. Here we fix vendors `min` amount. Since `$group` takes the smallest value, we replace it with next vendors `max` value:
   `{companyVendorId:1, max:500, min:50}, ---\ {companyVendorId:1, max:500, min:200},
   {companyVendorId:2, max:400, min:200}  ---/ {companyVendorId:2, max:400, min:200}`
6. Stage 8. Now we sum vendors with the same `companyVendorId` and `amount` between `min` and `max` values.
7. Stages 9-10-11. We flatten previous result, transform into desired out and sort documents.

---

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "date": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2019-12-31T23:59:59Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$month": "$date"
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "_id": {
            "$month": "$date"
          },
          "companyVendorId": "$companyVendorId",
          "amount": "$amount"
        }
      },
      "data2": {
        "$push": {
          "companyVendorId": "$companyVendorId",
          "amount": "$amount"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data2"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "month": "$_id",
        "companyVendorId": "$data2.companyVendorId"
      },
      "data": {
        "$first": "$data"
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": "$data2.amount"
      },
      "min": {
        "$min": "$data2.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id.month": 1,
      "max": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.month",
      "data": {
        "$first": "$data"
      },
      "data2": {
        "$push": {
          "companyVendorId": "$_id.companyVendorId",
          "max": "$max",
          "min": "$min"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data2: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $min: [
                  {
                    $size: "$data2"
                  },
                  2
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          as: "i",
          in: {
            companyVendorId: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data2.companyVendorId",
                "$$i"
              ]
            },
            max: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data2.max",
                "$$i"
              ]
            },
            min: {
              $ifNull: [
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$data2.max",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        "$$i",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$data2.min",
                    "$$i"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data3: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $slice: [
              "$data2",
              2
            ]
          },
          as: "topN",
          in: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$data",
              initialValue: {
                _id: "",
                companyVendorId: "$$topN.companyVendorId",
                amount: 0
              },
              in: {
                _id: "$_id",
                companyVendorId: "$$value.companyVendorId",
                amount: {
                  $add: [
                    "$$value.amount",
                    {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$value.companyVendorId",
                                "$$this.companyVendorId"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $gte: [
                                "$$this.amount",
                                "$$topN.min"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $lte: [
                                "$$this.amount",
                                "$$topN.max"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$this.amount",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data3"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data3"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
      amount: -1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wbM4Pb-C4fa)

**Note:** You need MongoDB `v4.2`. For earlier versions (`>v3.4`), replace:

```
{ $replaceWith: "$data3" }
         with 
{ $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data3" }}
```